# ASP.net vb Javascript time to call a routine

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I want to call a function using JavaScript. What I have is a JavaScript timeout that I want to call a classes routine. I want the routine to run after 3 seconds. Is this possible. All I really want is to call a function/routine from a class once the timer goes off.

HTML MarkUp

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
 <script type="text/jscript">
     setTimeout(function () {
         function CallingServerSideFunction() {
             PageMethods.GetLabelText();
         }
     }, 3000);

    </script>
```

Class

```
Public Shared Function GetLabelText()

    Return "Hello"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this document:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: web services are the simpler way you can find, moreover this is the "standard way" of doing this.

Comment: I created a fresh project to see how it worked. Added the WecService and the code Microsoft provided - however I get an error for this line. <%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="Samples.AspNet.SimpleWebService" %>
Which in turn breaks the program would happen to know why?